# Basis for a line bundle

Tags: differential-topology, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

I have a basic confusion. The following is drawn from Huybrechts' Complex Geometry text:

"Let $L$ be a holomorphic line bundle on a complex manifold $X$ and suppose that $s_0,\dots, s_n \in H^0(X, L)$ is a basis." (Prop. 2.3.26)

Here $H^0(X,L)$ is the space of (holomorphic) sections of the line bundle $L$.

What does it mean to have a basis for such a space? Indeed, the existence of a global frame makes any vector bundle trivial, so I presume he means something else.

Comment: I suppose a topological trivial line bundle is not necessarily a holomorphic trivial line bundle.

Comment: That's definitely true. But I don't think this answers my question. Perhaps he is viewing the space of holomorphic sections as a free module over the ring of holomorphic functions, and the basis he is referring to is the module basis? Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

A basis of sections does not provide a global frame. The sections permit zeros. Morally, one can think of the basis of sections as a basis in a function space. On the other hand a frame is a basis in the *bundle fibers* (as opposed to the space of *sections*). A priori, the space of sections could be infinite dimensional, but it is a nice fact that for $X$ compact, $H^0(X,L)$ is finite-dimensional. On the other hand, a frame always has $\mathrm{rank} L=1$ vector at each fiber. That is, a global frame for $L$ is provided by a single nonvanishing section.

Comment: If I have understood correctly, my mistake was to confuse the individual bundle fibers (which are each vector spaces), with the space of sections of the bundle, which is a module over the ring of smooth (continuous, holomorphic, ...) functions?  This module won't have rank 1 even on a line bundle. For instance, I guess that the mobius bundle would have rank 2?

Comment: Are you saying that $H^0(X,L)$ is finite-dimensional as a complex vector space for $X$ compact? That can't be right. Suppose $L$ is the trivial bundle $X \times \mathbb{C}$. Then $H^0(X,L)$ is the holomorphic functions on the manifold $X$, which is finite-dimensional only in boring cases.